# Puzzled at HTTP/2 301 response header

Tags: redirect, performance

I am running `curl -I https://padelove.gr/cart` with the `https://` part prepended explicitly, and I am noticing that the response header is about an HTTP/2 301 redirect on the very same URL. Shouldn't that be a 200 instead?

I've triple-checked that the .htaccess does not contain any `RewriteEngine`, `RewriteCond`, or `RewriteRule` lines, and I've even replaced the .htaccess file with the [default wordpress .htaccess](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/) but that doesn't make any difference whatsoever. I really don't know where this 301 is declared. On the browser a response of 200 can be seen in the Network tab of DevTools'.

I was trying to troubleshoot the page itself which is very slow to load on the browser, and I only discovered said output after trying to check with `curl -I` if HTTP/2 was actually used to serve it. Is this normal? Should I look elsewhere to troubleshoot the slow page load, or is this unusual and should be further investigated? If so, where should I look?

Comment: A 301 redirect to where? Note that there is no such thing as a URL without a protocol part on the front, curl will be adding one for you if you don't add it yourself. As for the browser, the browser is showing a 200 for the page it was redirected to, even if it got a 301 it would follow it and that would be a brand new request, the 301 wouldn't be listed unless you had told the browser tools to preserve network data across requests. Otherwise, just to clarify, you're asking what the cause of the 301 redirect is? Or are you asking how to debug it? You need to ask a specific Q

Comment: Is it just a redirect from `/shop` to `/shop/`?

Comment: @kero Nice catch. That is indeed what's happening. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @TomJNowell Indeed there is not, and I wanted to make sure it would go directly to the https version, and make sure to avoid another 301 redirect due to typing only the domain name. Running `curl -I padelove.gr/cart/` (with the trailing slash) outputs another 301 redirect from http to https. As for preserving network data across requests, I am familiar with that feature and use it often. I am experiencing slow loading page times because of the lack of caching for `cart` and `checkout` pages, and was suspecting that to be partially due to the redirect from `/cart` to `/cart/`, but was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that WordPress is just redirecting to the version with trailing slash.

- `/cart` => `/cart/`
- `/shop` => `/shop/`

I'm having trouble, finding a good canonical source why WP is doing this. The fact is, that most web frameworks (I worked with) will force trailing slashes on their routes (that are not directed at files).

If you want to read more: there is [this blog post on trailing slashes and URIs in general](https://blog.cdivilly.com/2019/02/28/uri-trailing-slashes), and [this StackOverflow thread has some good points as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/when-should-i-use-a-trailing-slash-in-my-url).

Comment: Thanks for sharing those. Especially the S.O. link I found it very insightful.

Comment: @KonstantinosSakkas did this answer your question? If so please mark it as the accepted answer via the check button under the voting controls so that Kero can get reputation points and the site knows the question was answered

Comment: Thanks for the prompt. I̶ ̶t̶r̶i̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶a̶m̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶e̶i̶v̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶p̶o̶p̶u̶p̶:̶ ̶T̶h̶a̶n̶k̶s̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶e̶e̶d̶b̶a̶c̶k̶!̶ ̶Y̶o̶u̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶l̶e̶a̶s̶t̶ ̶1̶5̶ ̶r̶e̶p̶u̶t̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶a̶s̶t̶ ̶a̶ ̶v̶o̶t̶e̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶f̶e̶e̶d̶b̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶h̶a̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶e̶n̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶o̶r̶d̶e̶d̶.̶